# Sitecore GlassMapper MVC add standard fields to model

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, glass-mapper

I need the sort order of my item in a specific model.

I have tried it like this but no luck:

```
[SitecoreField("__Sortorder")]
public string SortOrder { get; set; }
```

Any idea how I can include standard fields in my model?

If this is not possible, actually I am working with a Checklist in that case, The AutoMapping from GlassMapper does return it in alphabetical order.

Here is the Definition of the Checklist Field:

```
IEnumerable<Guid> Filter_Tags_To_Shows  {get; set;}
```

And like mentioned before, the list is returned in alphabetical order but I have no change to sort afterwards since missing the sortOrder field.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What issue are you having with the code above? Is Glass not mapping the field at all or is it mapping the field but with incorrect values? Have you tried changing the field type to int instead of string?

Comment: Yes int returns 0 , string returns null. So I think there is no mapping done. But there is a sortorder value on that item.

Comment: Can you try moving your field to a class called Appearance and decorate the class with a SitecoreType decorator with the TemplateId of the Appearance class where that field actually comes from? Just as a test. Maybe with your version of Glass, you need the field to exist on the template that your class represents (I have no idea if that was ever a requirement with any version of Glass).

Comment: Can you add to your question the details around the checklist field?  You had mentioned this in a comment to another answer but the answer has been removed.

Comment: Ok updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Filter_Tags_To_Shows` property is returning a list of `Guid`s which, I presume, you are then doing something to get the linked Item from Sitecore. This is not the most efficient way and Glass allows you to specify the linked Item type which it will them automap.

```
IEnumerable<FilterTagClass> Filter_Tags_To_Shows  {get; set;}
```

Assuming that the `FilterTagClass` has the sort order specified like in your question:

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId={GUID})]
public class FilterTagClass : GlassBase 
{
    [SitecoreField("__Sortorder")]
    public virtual int SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

You can sort using Linq:

```
@foreach (var tag in Filter_Tags_To_Shows.OrderBy(i => i.SortOrder))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

This is a re-hash of the answer from @DougCouto but note it is not necessary to convert IDs to object if you set up the properties and mapping correctly.

As an alternative to using the `Checklist` field you can use the `Multilist` field, which will allow you select tags and re-order them as required. Glass should return them in the same order you have set then.

Answer (score 1):

This property

```
IEnumerable<Guid> Filter_Tags_To_Shows  {get; set;}
```

will give you a list of IDs for the items that you selected in the checklist field.  To get the sortorder of the actual items, you need to convert these IDs into objects:

```
var tagsToShow = Filter_Tags_To_Shows.Select(i => SitecoreContext.GetItem<SomeClassType>(i));
```

Assuming **SomeClassType** has the **SortOrder** field, you should then be able to access that field for each object in **tagsToShow** and do something like this:

```
var sortedTagsToShow = tagsToShow.OrderBy(i => i.Sortorder);
```

Comment: Thank you DoughCouto. Like mentioned before I added the SortOrder field to SomeClassType but the value is 0 as int and null as string. Somehow GlassMapper does not automap this. Maybe I will convert them to real Sitecore Items, then I have the sortorder field.

Answer (score 0):

Checklist and Multilist are stored as raw text in the Sitecore database and the sequence will be updated based on data source item sequences, You can try the sample below.

```
Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField multilistField = item.Fields["FieldName"];

foreach (var child in multilistField.GetItems)
{
    // It should provide in short order
}
```